# SP2010: Value of the 'Title' field is not stored when saving from pagelayout

Tags: content-type, page-layout

I've created a pagelayout associated with a specific content type that contains the standard Title field.
In my aspx file, I have an *EditModePanel* with attribute *PageDisplayMode* set to *Edit*, and inside this panel I have a *TextField* associated with the Title field of my page.
The problem is that when I try to change the value of this field, it's not stored and I always see the original title (the one I defined in the page creation default SP form).
All other fields are correctly stored.

If I go to the Pages library and edit the Title field using the SharePoint standard edit form, I can change the Title value.

Could someone tell me why it's not working within the PageLayout, or what could produce this strange behaviour ? (There's no event receiver associated with the Pages library)

Here's a piece of code of my page :

```
<PublishingWebControls:EditModePanel runat="server" PageDisplayMode="Edit">
    <table ...><tr><td>
        <SharePointWebControls:TextField FieldName="Title" runat="server"></SharePointWebControls:TextField>
        ... other field (NoteField, RichHtmlField, ...)
    </td></tr></table>
</PublishingWebControls:EditModePanel>
```